# C# Entity Framework: Check & Execute Logic (Multiple users)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, concurrency

I've designed a WPF application using Entity Framework for data persistence. All interaction with the database is done through the Entity Framework infrastructure.

I'd like to check a boolean property on a specific Entity, and if it is false, execute some logic against this entity and related entities. However, the application is used in a multi-user environment, and so potentially the code can pass the check (i.e. the boolean property can be false), but another user can intercept and only the latest user's changes will be saved (as per optimistic concurrency).

How can I wrap the check and the updates to the entity and related entities, so that either all the code gets executed, or none of the code? I understand that Transactions might be the solution to this problem? If so, how are these implemented in the Entity Framework?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to update the deciding property before performing the rest of the logic?

Answer (score 2):

```
using (var context = new YourContext()) 
            { 
                using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
                { 
                    try 
                    { 
                      //Your logic here
                        context.SaveChanges(); 

                        dbContextTransaction.Commit(); 
                    } 
                    catch (Exception) 
                    { 
                        dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); 
                    } 
                } 
            }
```

Comment: This does the trick, thanks a lot! Before I mark as the accepted answer, I picked up some interesting behavior. When I put a breakpoint in the middle of the transaction to create a conflict on purpose, the other users will 'hang' on context.SaveChanges() until the server times out. I'd prefer not to mess with the current Timeout limits. Is there some strategy to pick up that a transaction is in place and cancel / move out of the context.SaveChanges() for the users that experience the 'hang'?

Comment: I dont understand you properly but you can check this on the transaction object    if (Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status == TransactionStatus.Committed) 
{
    // do redirect
}

Comment: Sorry for the out of context info i will look into the transaction object and find out how to do that

Comment: try a Boolean value at the beginning of the method, toggle its value when a transaction is commited. With this you can use the Boolean value as a flag to continue or not.Let me know if this helps